# Como consistir um data frame contra um vetor de valores válidos?

Tags: r, for

Tenho um vetor com todos os possíveis valores que aparecem num conjunto de colunas de um data frame. O numero de componentes no vetor é diferente do numero de observações do data frame.

Meu objetivo é identificar as observações inválidas no data frame. A solução abaixo funcionou, mas não estou satisfeito pois gostaria de não usar o `for` para loop.

`DF` é um data frame com 4 colunas nomeadas de `da1` a `da4` e 9 linhas de observações. `DF` foi importada de uma planilha excel, bem como "check" que é uma tabela excel com uma única coluna.

```
str(DF)
DF1 <- DF
DF1 <- as.data.frame(DF) # transformo DF em data frame
str(DF1)
```

`result` é um vetor lógico de comprimento igual ao número de linhas de observações de `DF1`.

`result1` é um data frame lógico obtido de `DF`.

```
result <- logical(length=9) 
result1 <- as.data.frame(result)
```

O loop abaixo verifica se cada coluna de `DF1` possui ou não algum elemento de "check". `result1` é o data frame lógico resultante.

```
for (col in 1:4) {
  diag <- DF1[, col] 
  result1[,col] <- is.element(diag,check) 
  }
result1
```

Comment: `result1 <- sapply(DF1, function(x) x %in% check)`.

Answer (score 1):

Não é necessário um loop explícito, um loop `*apply` é mais simples.

```
result1 <- sapply(DF1, function(x) x %in% check)
result1 <- as.data.frame(result1)

result1
#     V1    V2    V3    V4
#1 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#2  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#3 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#4 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#5 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#6 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#7  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#8  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#9 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Tendo em conta que na pergunta é utilizada a função `is.element`, veja-se que dá resultados idênticos.

```
identical(
  sapply(DF1, is.element, check), 
  sapply(DF1, function(x) x %in% check)
)
#[1] TRUE
```

**Dados**

```
set.seed(2020)
n <- 9
DF1 <- replicate(4, sample(10, n, TRUE))
DF1 <- as.data.frame(DF1)
check <- sample(10, 6)
```

Comment: O que o `is.element` verifica? Se é um elemento? Elemento é algum tipo de dado do R?

Comment: No R um vetor pode ser o que imaginamos ser um vetor (da matemática) mas também pode ser um objeto de classe `"list"`. Elemento não é um tipo de dado, é uma designação genérica, a que estamos habituados e em R é a preferida para "vetores", para "listas" prefere-se "member/membro". Quanto à função `is.element`, veja [help('is.element')](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html) ou no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19136456/8245406). Boa pergunta, já agora.